# How do I fill a form in a web site that calls javascript code and retrieve the results from a different frame using python?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, web

I'm going to have to code a program in python that retrieves results after filling a web form (which in turn calls different javascript functions), and those results appear in a different frame of the website. I considered using the Selenium web engine, but I was wondering if anyone has any better idea?

Thank you

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea. Reverse engineer the javascript using the chrome/firefox console, see what request it makes and mimic them in python using urllib2 or the requests library.